# Oracle database: using Char(X) or Numeric(X) instead of Date

Tags: java, oracle, performance, date

I have found some issues with the `date` type in Oracle databases. I have to manage an important amount of data, and they don't seem to work as well as expected with indexes and other stuff. The important thing is that I have decided to use another type for it.

My options are:

- `numeric(8)` for "date" and `numeric(6)` for "time"
- `char(8)` for "date" and `char(6)` for "time"

The fields are formatted as `YYYYMMAA` for date and `HHMMSS` for time.

The order of priorities (pondered) are:

1. Performance querying the fields separately (x3.5)
2. Performance querying the fields joined as one (date + time) (x3)
3. Usability from java (x2)
4. Legibility of the database (x1)

Which type would you suggest to use and why?

Thanks! :)

Comment: performance will be crap if you have to do any "date math", e.g. "where datefield  < 2 days old" type stuff, because your values aren't native dates/times, meaning you'll either have to convert on-the-fly to actual native date/times values, or implement your own date math systems.

Comment: "*I have found some issues with the `date` type*" - and which issues are that? I'm pretty sure any other "solution" (varchar, numeric) will give you **way** more "issues" than the `date` data type. "*What would you suggest*" - store dates in a `date` (or `timestamp`) column. There is no sensible alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ISO 8601

When you *must* serialize a date-time value as a string, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Here are examples of a few of the formats:

> Date-only example: 2015-10-18
>
> Date-time example: 2015-10-18T14:26:16Z
>
> Week-of-year: 2015-W42

This entire standard is surprisingly well thought-out and practical. The strings alphabetical order also happen to be chronological (when in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), and when consistent with resolving to whole or fraction of the second).

The hyphens are optional, considered by the spec to be the the "basic" version of the formats; I suggest including the hyphens unless storage/memory is critically scarce. The hyphens make the strings recognizable as date-time representations, and are easier to read by humans.

When creating reports, exporting data, writing XML or JSON, or otherwise exchanging data, I suggest almost always using these standard formats. Both (a) the new java.time framework built into Java 8 and later, (b) the Joda-Time library use these formats by default when parsing and generating string representations of date-time values.

### Specifications Discordance

Note that while both ISO 8601 and the SQL standard are decades old, they seemed to have not crossed paths. The SQL standard has similar formats but not quite the same. Specifically ISO 8601 uses a `T` between the date and time-of-day portions whereas the SQL spec never does so.

Also some proprietary types use their own string formats, such as Oracle 11g using `DD-MON-YY` as the default for `DATE` type, for example `'13-NOV-92'`.

### java.time

The java.time framework built into Java 8 and later has extended the ISO 8601 format for date-time by appending the name of the time zone in brackets.

The standard uses only an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A true time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for making adjustments for anomalies such as [Daylight Savings Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

## Use The Data-Type, Luke

Like the others commenting, I *strongly* recommend you learn and use your database’s native data types for date-time work. Some like SQLite have weak support for date-time, but most have decent to excellent support (such as [H2](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html) and [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)).

These data types vary widely. The SQL spec defines some, but some databases such as Oracle additionally have proprietary types. Often those proprietary types are old outmoded types.

Even the standard data types are not so standard. You should play around and experiment outside your project so as to cement your understanding of their behavior.

The "issues" you experienced are most likely a misunderstanding of the specific type or of date-time handling in general. If so, rolling you own data type (via strings) will only exacerbate your problems in the long run. Invest some time in searching StackOverflow to learn about date-time handling. The subject of date-time is surprisingly tricky.

### Numbers

As for using numbers as a roll-your-own date-time type, nearly all the native date-time data types use numbers internally. So no performance advantage in doing your own.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use still a date type. It will be stored as a number anyway ;) . But if you preffer to store it as a number or char, the 20151019 as a number makes more sense :) (also from size & performance perspective) btw, date format will be even smaller